# How to find the first result based on summed rows in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'ID':[101762, 101762, 101762, 102842, 102842, 106755, 106755, 106755, 108615, 108615, 113402, 113402, 114711, 114711],
        'Year':[2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020],
        'Amount':[6000, 2000, 3330.00, 846.19, 846.19, 16185.00, 815, 800, 281496.00, 1363730.00, 19815.00, 9585.00, 64332.70, 5400.00]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

This is where I am now.

[image]

This is where I want to be.

[image]

I got some huge help from BENY today. Here is the code that I have now.

```
out = df.sort_values('Year',ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID','Amount']).sort_values('Amount').groupby('ID').agg({'Year':'last','Amount':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

That is summing the 2019 & 2020 Amounts together. I want to sum the 2019 Amount, per ID, and compare that to the sum of 2020 Amounts, per ID, and keep the larger one.

Sorry for the multiple posts today, but I just figured out my last question didn't account for a bug in one system that I work with.

I tried two ideas, shown below. Neither worked.

```
out = df.sort_values(['ID'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID']).sort_values('Amount').groupby(['ID','Year']).agg({'Amount':'sum'}).reset_index()
out

out = df.sort_values(['ID','Year'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID','Year']).sort_values('Amount').groupby(['ID','Year']).agg({'Amount':'sum'}).reset_index()
out
```

Here is an update. This gets me pretty close.

```
out = df.sort_values(['ID','Year'],ascending=True).sort_values('Amount').groupby(['ID','Year']).agg({'Amount':'sum'}).reset_index()
out = out.sort_values(['Year','ID'],ascending=True).drop_duplicates(['ID'], keep='first')
out
```

The final result looks like this.

```
        ID  Year     Amount
0   101762  2019    8000.00
2   102842  2019     846.19
4   106755  2019   17000.00
6   108615  2019  281496.00
8   113402  2019   19815.00
10  114711  2019   64332.70
```

The only problem I see is that this:

```
108615  2019  281496.00
```

Should be this:

```
108615  2020  1363730.00
```

Basically, if the sum of Amount for 2020 is larger, I want to show that and if the sum of 2019 Amount is larger, I want to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# groupby ID and year and get the sum
g = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
# assign a new column called maxval to the max value of each groupped ID and filter
g[g['Amount'] == g.assign(maxval=g.groupby('ID').transform(max)['Amount'])['maxval']]

        ID  Year      Amount
0   101762  2019     8000.00
2   102842  2019      846.19
3   102842  2020      846.19
4   106755  2019    16985.00
7   108615  2020  1363730.00
8   113402  2019    19815.00
10  114711  2019    64332.70
```

Comment: I just figured out another way ton do the same thing:

out = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
out = out.sort_values(['ID','Amount'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID'], keep='first')
out